# Superscript text in GIMP

Tags: gimp, text, typography, typesetting

How can I add superscript text to text in GIMP? I am looking for other solutions than adding another textbox with just smaller font size...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There is no superscript text feature in GIMP. However you could select the text you want to make into a superscript, make it a lower font size, and move the baseline up.  This is an entirely manual operation. [see example](https://imgur.com/Xb8xdew).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went the way [Billy Kerr](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/89608/billy-kerr) describes in [his comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159298/superscript-text-in-gimp?noredirect=1#comment240609_159298):

[image]

Having text with fontsize of 80 px, I raised the baseline of the superscript text by 40 px and set the font size to 60 px.

As a rule of thumb, you can raise the baseline by 50% of your fontsize and lower the fontsize of your superscript by 25%. I'm not a typography SME, but those values are close to what browsers use as defaults to style [`<sup>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp) tags.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your font, you may be able to use the superscript characters in Unicode, which you can copy-paste from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Latin,_Greek_and_Cyrillic_tables). Be aware that these letters are not designed to display words and a lot of fonts have bad kerning or style them differently.

Here's how the table from wikipedia looks in my browser's default font:

[image: wikipedia table]